# How to have a jupyter script running 24/7 on a ubuntu droplet

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

a quick question concerning remote servers (or what I understand to be such thing):

I am running python scripts on a ubuntu droplet (from digitalocean.com) on a windows pc. I am working on jupyter, accessing it via the PuTTY-client by typing:

```py
jupyter notebook --browser any
```

and then opening my browser to run my scripts (all stored on the server). I would like to have scripts running, even when I am not logged in via the PuTTY-client

To achieve this, I tried writing a never-ending script like this:

```py
while True:
     ...
```

and closed everything. Understandably, when I open the notebook again, it shows a "keyboard interrupt error" - no one likes to be alone ;).

My question is, how I can automate a python script on my server, without having to be logged in with my pc?

Thank you for your ideas and experience. I am new to python and operations on remote servers, so I am glad I got this far!